# BigQuery on GAE: Running data based on Developer's access

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm developing an app using bigquery and I own all the underlying data.
I would like to expose users to a sub-set of this data, with their scope of access determined by permissions control that I want to implement.
I do not want to grant them any access to the bigquery tables.

My question is:
How do I set things up so that when they run something, it's based on my access to the table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to let users write their own queries? If so, then this would be difficult, unless you can partition the data into tables on a per-user basis. Or you could play games with rewriting the query -- if they do `select foo from bar ...` you could replace the table name with `(select allowed columns from underlying.table where user_id = 'current_user')`.

If you are going to be generating the queries on behalf of the users, then you can just use your own credentials (or your service account's creds) to access bigquery. Essentially you just need an OAuth2 refresh token, and this should be valid forever. One way of thinking about it is if you had a mysql database, you'd access that with your own credentials not the user's.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. One follow-up question that I have is: looking at the latest examples of oauth2 for app engine, there doesn't seem to be anywhere where a token is involved. So I'm not quite sure how I can run a query on behalf of the user.